# how to implement rabbitmq in nodejs

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

```
Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined

> Blockquote
```

> Blockquote

```
    var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');        
        amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
          conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
            var q = 'hello';        
            ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
            console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
            ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
              console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
            }, {noAck: true});
          });
        });

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');    
        amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {         
          conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
            var q = 'hello';
            var msg = 'Hello World!';        
            ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
            // Note: on Node 6 Buffer.from(msg) should be used
            ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
            console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
          });

        });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined
            at D:\samadhan\Projects\RabbitMQ\sender.js:7:8
            at D:\samadhan\Projects\RabbitMQ\node_modules\amqplib\callback_api.js:16:10
            at Socket. (D:\samadhan\Projects\RabbitMQ\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connect.js:187:18)
            at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:324:30)
            at emitOne (events.js:125:13)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:221:7)
            at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

```
    D:\samadhan\Projects\RabbitMQ>enter code here
```

Comment: You really should check `err`, I bet you'll find something interesting.

Comment: @LukeBakken Please ref : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278469/how-to-authenticate-rabbitmq-in-nodejs)